# An adjective for a "scene" that has a lot of different things in it?

Tags: single-word-requests

Considering all different views, we see how ----- the scene about phenomenon X is.

I want an adjective for the blank above, an adjective that means "containing a lot of different things".

I found this word "[varietal](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/varietal)" but it seems to be used mostly for biological usages.

Comment: I would say a "*busy* scene", if I had to come up with a term without having any context.  Do you have some context?

Comment: how about "diverse"?

Answer (score 3):

Although it seems too obvious, "complex" seems sufficient.

Complex: "A whole made up of complicated or interrelated parts." M-W

Answer (score 0):

I’m not clear how literal your context is,
or how much you want a metaphorical term,
or what tone you want,
but ***cluttered*** literally means “containing a lot of different things”
with a derogatory connotation.